# Finding YTD Change and MoM Change

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

my table looks something like this:

| Sector | 4/1/2022 | 5/1/2022 | 6/1/2022 | 1Y Min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 05 | 12 | 05 |
| B | 18 | 20 | 09 | 09 |
| C | 02 | 09 | 12 | 02 |

1. I want to add a new column "1m change" such that values of the new column is calculated using the formula: (Value as of the latest date - Value as of one month prior to the latest date)
2. I want to add a new column "YTD change" such that values of the new column is calculated using the formula: (Value as of the latest date - Value as of first date of the year)

I want to keep both the formulas dynamic such that it gets updated whenever a column with a new date is available.

For eg:-

| Sector | 1/1/2022 | 5/1/2022 | 6/1/2022 | 1Y Min | 1M Change | YTD Chg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 05 | 12 | 05 | 7 | 2 |
| B | 20 | 20 | 60 | 09 | 40 | 40 |
| C | 02 | 09 | 12 | 02 | 3 | 10 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df['1M Change'] = np.nan
df['YTD Chg'] = np.nan


df['1M Change'] = df.iloc[:, -4] - df.iloc[:, -5]
df['YTD Chg'] = df.iloc[:, -4] - df.iloc[:, 1]

def aaa():
    df['1M Change'] = df.iloc[:, -4] - df.iloc[:, -5]
    df['YTD Chg'] = df.iloc[:, -4] - df.iloc[:, 1]

df.insert(1, "lost", [2, 1, 3], True)
aaa()

print(df)
```

Immediately added columns: 1M Change, YTD Chg and filled them with empty values. Implicit [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) indexing is used (row index numbers on the left, column index numbers on the right). At the end, I added a column and called in the function to update the columns 1M Change, YTD Chg.